# Intersection of Two Arrays - Space Time And Complexity

Tags: array, complexity

The problem is as follows: Given two arrays, write a function to compute their intersection.

The below code is my solution.I'm just curious as to what the space time and complexity of below algorithm would be.

```
var intersection = function(nums1, nums2) {
    const intersectionArr =  nums1.filter((value)=> nums2.includes(value));
    return [...new Set(intersectionArr)];
};
```

Comment: Please add tag of the language in which this is written (I suppose js?) Despite i think question purely about complexity iss offtopic on this site, the time complexity Is probably O(n^2) And Space Is O(n).